# How do I start crawling with multiple URLs of the same format in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

My Scrapy spider needs to start with URLs of the following format:

```
https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?searchArg={$variable}&searchCode=GKEY%5E*&searchType=1&limitTo=none&fromYear=&toYear=&limitTo=LOCA%3Dall&limitTo=PLAC%3Dall&limitTo=TYPE%3Dall&limitTo=LANG%3Dall&recCount=1000'
```

where $variable is a parameter that can be fed with as many values as possible (possibly even 1000 possible values).

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You could overwrite the [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method to something like:

```
def start_requests(self):
    base_url = 'https://catalog.loc.gov/vwebv/search?...'
    variables = [...]
    for variable in variables:
        url = base_url.format(variable)
        yield Request(url)
```